# Get members from each team via SQL JOINS

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, `members`, `teams` & `team_members`.

`team_members` houses the ids from both the `members` & `teams` and stores them per row.

The schema of the`team_members` table:

[image]

`teams` table:

What I'd like to be able to do is create a join where i can output the `team_name` from the `teams` table and then underneth show the `members_firstname` associated with that that team. So example:

```
Team 1
joe bloggs
jon doe

Team 2
charlie chaplin
hulk hogan
```

My php code looks like this:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$sql = "SELECT t.team_name, group_concat(m.firstName) 
        FROM members AS m
        JOIN team_members AS tm
        ON tm.member_id = m.member_id 
        JOIN teams as t
        on t.team_id = tm.team_id
        GROUP BY t.teamname"; 

$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row["member_id"] . '<br>';
            echo $row["team_id"] . '<br><br>';      
        }
    }
?>
```

Now I get:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in -- on line 30 which is:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
```

Comment: You need to supply the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @JBES im struggling to understand how to make the `JOIN` but ill put in the question where I am at...

Comment: Very rough example... `select t.teamname, group_concat(m.name) from members as m join teammembers as tm on tm.memberid = m.memberid join teams as t on t.teamid = tm.teamid group by t.teamname`

Comment: @chris85 so how would I then output the team name followed by the members...

Comment: @chris85 so iv adjusted it slightly to reflect my table data but i get `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in `

Comment: The query failed do error checking for why.

Comment: @chris85 iv updated my question

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133206/discussion-between-phpdude-and-chris85).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use two joins to piece together the three tables.

```
SELECT t.team_name as team_name, group_concat(m.firstName) as team_members 
FROM members AS m
JOIN team_members AS tm
ON tm.member_id = m.member_id 
JOIN teams as t
on t.team_id = tm.team_id
GROUP BY t.team_name
```

You then should check the status of your `query` before trying to work with it.

```
if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)) {
     die(printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error));
}
```

Then loop through the results, and split the grouped values by the comma.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      echo $row["team_name"] . '<br>';
      $names = explode(',', $row['team_members']);
      foreach($names as $name) {
           echo $name . '<br>';
       }
       echo '<br>';      
}
```

You also could use `<br>` as the separator in the `group_concat`. You can read more about that function here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat. If you did that you can get rid of the `foreach` and `explode` because the `$row['team_members']` would be built with a linebreak for each member.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this in PHP is width two nested loops in first you go trought the team table and print it in the second you print all the playes width theat team id...

Something like:

```
 do{
      echo $row_team;

      do{
           echo $row_playa;
      }while($row_plya = mysql_fetch_assoc($playas));    // whear pleya.team_id = $row_team.id

 }while($row_team = mysql_fetch_assoc($teams));
```

Comment: `mysql_*` should not be used. Also this wouldn't be the `easiest` way, having mysql do it would be easiest.